# What is the difference between taking a slice and taking a reference to an array as argument?

Tags: arrays, generics, rust, slice

What is the difference between taking a slice:

```
fn relu(xs: &mut [f64]) {
    xs.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = x.max(0.0));
}
```

and taking a reference to an array

```
fn relu<const L: usize>(xs: &mut [f64; L]) {
    xs.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = x.max(0.0));
}
```

as argument?

Does either have its uses or is one strictly better than the other?

Answer (score 4):

Well, a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) is more general, since there are more types that can be used:

```rust
fn relu(xs: &mut [f64]) {
    xs.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = x.max(0.0));
}
```

You could call `relu` over a `&mut Vec`, `&mut []`, or `&mut [_; N]` (pretty much anything that you can make a slice from, remember that a slice is just a view over some continuous sequence), because those types can be used as slices.

Meanwhile:

```rust
fn relu<const L: usize>(xs: &mut [f64; L]) {
    xs.iter_mut().for_each(|x| *x = x.max(0.0));
}
```

Can only be use in a `[f64; L]`, **and** a new function is generated for each `L` used, <s>which in this case is pretty much a lose of resources</s> .

As @Masklinn comments:

> OTOH a reference to an array means the iteration size is definitely
> known at compile-time, which can allow optimisations which the slice
> version may not be able to work out. So sometimes using an array
> reference can make sense as an optimisation assistance (in this case
> relu would probably be a major candidate for inlining so the important
> bit would really be what the type is in the caller).

Comment: OTOH a reference to an array means the iteration size is definitely known at compile-time, which can allow optimisations which the slice version may not be able to work out. So sometimes using an array reference can make sense as an optimisation assistance (in this case `relu` would probably be a major candidate for inlining so the important bit would really be what the type is in the caller).

Comment: @Masklinn, indeed, good point, thanks!, may I add it as part of the answer, or would you like to add it yourself?

Comment: Nah go ahead, it's really just a side-note so readers don't assume references to arrays are always *errors* (unlike, say, shared references to vecs or strings)

Comment: Another disadvantage of array references is that they are monomorphized, causing code bloat. Even though the optimizer is likely to deduplicate them it'll still take some extra time.